# Positioning UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have an iphone app where i display a series of images. When the user taps an image i need to bring that image to the first position,indicating it is the selected image. I am able to achieve the tap in uiscrollview by means of subclassing.But I am not able to position the imageview to the first in uiscrollview. Please help out of this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the scroll view to a desired position using *contentOffset* property. You can calculate the image position using the touch position. For example, if the images are scrolled horizontally,

```
float _x = touchedX - (touchedX % imageViewWidth);
CGPoint contentOffset = CGPointMake(_x, 0); // to scroll horizontally
[scrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

if u know the position of the imageview in the scrollview, then u can make it to show in the view with the help of `setContentOffset:animated:` in UIScrollView.

Hope this would help you.